# How to add Shipping Cost in Total Amount in Stripe Checkout?

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments, stripes

I want to add Shipping Cost to the total checkout amount. I am using the stripe prebuild checkout page to complete the payment. When I enabled the Shipping option in Strip Session, Stripe started displaying the Shipping Address Form (that I don't want to display) on the checkout page.

I don't want to take the user's shipping address, I have already done this.

I tried to read the Stripe DCOS but didn't find the solution on this, If anyone can help me will be a great pleasure.

Answer (score 4):

Here is how I have done it you can add many objects in shipping_options  to have many shipping types

```
const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
  payment_method_types: ['card'],
  mode: 'payment',
  shipping_options: [
    {
      shipping_rate_data: {
        type: 'fixed_amount',
        fixed_amount: {
          amount: 1500,
          currency: 'usd',
        },
        display_name: 'Next day air',
        delivery_estimate: {
          minimum: {
            unit: 'business_day',
            value: 1,
          },
          maximum: {
            unit: 'business_day',
            value: 1,
          },
        },
      },
    },
  ],
  line_items: data.map((el) => {
    return {
      price_data: {
        currency: 'usd',
        product_data: {
          name: el.title,
          //   images: [el.img],
        },
        unit_amount: 1000,
      },
      quantity: 1,
    };
  }),
  success_url: '{{yoursite}}/success',
  cancel_url: '{{yoursite}}/cancel',
});

enter code here
```

Also, you can check their docs [here](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/shipping)

Answer (score 0):

You could just add it as a one-time [item in the Checkout Session](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-line_items).